# How do I start Run Window (Windows key + R) from Windows Command Prompt? I also want to define WHAT program Run should open in the same command

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

I want to make a batch file to-

Open Windows 10 Mail app using Run Window.

The run window should be launched by using cmd with parameter set as :

***outlookmail:***

that launched Mail app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd` isn't an automation tool. Anyhow - you don't need the "Run" box at all.

In a `cmd` window (or a batchfile), just enter:

```
start outlookmail:
```

Comment: FYI, CMD always tries to find a command by searching `PATH` and appending the `PATHEXT` file extensions. If it finds a file, it first tries `CreateProcessW` and, if that fails, usually falls back on `ShellExecuteExW`. The latter not only opens/executes files, but also supports opening a directory in an Explorer window and running registered "App Paths" commands and protocols such as "http:", "shell:" and "outlookmail:". However, the latter special cases are only available when using the `start` command, which tries `ShellExecuteExW` even if no file is found.